# CSS grid-row property no behaving as expected in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm currently going through a course on Udemy for front end development. While going through on of the videos I ran into a weird problem when using the CSS grid layout.

As you can see in the pictures I am getting different results for the layout depending on the width of the browser window. I'm not sure why this is happening.

[Small Browser Wdith](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSTIb.png)

[Full Browser Width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jodZ.png)

I expected the layout in the smaller window, first image, to look similar to what is seen in the larger window. Does anyone know why this change occurs when the widths are different sizes?

The relevant CSS code is below. The green class selects all of the elements with the green background and sets the number of columns and rows they should span.

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.green {
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: 1/3;
}
```

Comment: *As you can see in the pictures I am getting different results for the layout depending on the width of the browser window. I'm not sure why this is happening* **because you have `auto-fill` which will create new columns when there's space available** and so the layout won't be consistent

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was not aware that this was caused by using auto-fill for the repeat value.